# Is the ability of reading NFC-tags in smartphones specified?

Tags: nfc

Is the NFC-reading-module in smart phones in a way specified (e.g. in ISO 18092) as that every smart phone has the same 'power' of reading NFC-tags. I am not an electrical engineer. What I am trying to ask is, if the reading process in respect to the distance between the smartphone and the NFC-Tag is the same at every smart phone because every NFC-reading-module is the same, or if there are differences between smartphones as that one smartphone can read tags where the difference is like 5cm and another one can read tags with distance to the phone about 10cm?

I hope my question is clear. It is a little bit hard for me to phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From experience I know that NFC performance varies very much among different smartphone models.

And there is no reason to assume that they use only one type of NFC chip; and even if they did there are other very important factors that can make a diference:

- RF PA (if not included in NFC chip)
- antenna design (and RF relevant design of the whole device)
- matching network

Also the max. distance for NFC not only depends on the terminal side (i.e. smartphone that provides power via RF) but also on the type of tag or NFC card that consumes the power. A NFC smart card that perform cryptographic operation needs much more power than a dumb NFC tag that just answers a few fixed bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, the reading distance can be up to 10cm but depending on surrounding electronics/metal/"How is the device held" and so on can influence on the distance.

From : https://nfc-forum.org/what-is-nfc/about-the-technology/

*ISO/IEC 14443 and FeliCa, which allow communications at distances **up to** 10 cm.*

*NFC complements many popular consumer level wireless technologies, by utilizing the key elements in existing standards for contactless card technology (ISO/IEC 14443 A&B and JIS-X 6319-4).*

Answer (score 1):

Not all smartphones have the same NFC chips built in, and it's not just the NFC chip that defines how far a tag can be away and still be able to be read. On my Xperia XZ for example I can't hold an NTAG213 tag further than 2cm.

The only thing you can be pretty sure about is that any smartphone with NFC will be able to read it 1cm far away, any wider just can't be said in general.